# Zip with password on the terminal (Ubuntu 20.04)

Tags: zip

I am running the command

> zip -p mypassword archieve.zip -r downloads/

and it creates a file

> mypassword.zip

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To know how a command works, try first the `--help` option and/or the `man` pages (if available).

In my `zip` in (Ubuntu 22.04).

```
$ zip --help
Copyright (c) 1990-2008 Info-ZIP - Type 'zip "-L"' for software license.
Zip 3.0 (July 5th 2008). Usage:
zip [-options] [-b path] [-t mmddyyyy] [-n suffixes] [zipfile list] [-xi list]
  The default action is to add or replace zipfile entries from list, which
  can include the special name - to compress standard input.
  If zipfile and list are omitted, zip compresses stdin to stdout.
  -f   freshen: only changed files  -u   update: only changed or new files
  -d   delete entries in zipfile    -m   move into zipfile (delete OS files)
  -r   recurse into directories     -j   junk (don't record) directory names
  -0   store only                   -l   convert LF to CR LF (-ll CR LF to LF)
  -1   compress faster              -9   compress better
  -q   quiet operation              -v   verbose operation/print version info
  -c   add one-line comments        -z   add zipfile comment
  -@   read names from stdin        -o   make zipfile as old as latest entry
  -x   exclude the following names  -i   include only the following names
  -F   fix zipfile (-FF try harder) -D   do not add directory entries
  -A   adjust self-extracting exe   -J   junk zipfile prefix (unzipsfx)
  -T   test zipfile integrity       -X   eXclude eXtra file attributes
  -y   store symbolic links as the link instead of the referenced file
  -e   encrypt                      -n   don't compress these suffixes
  -h2  show more help
```

Note there's the `-h2` to show more help. But `man zip` will give you the full docs.

```
$ man zip
...
OPTIONS
...
       -p
       --paths
              Include relative file paths as part of the names of files stored in the archive.  This is the default.  The -j option junks the paths and just stores the names of the files.

       -P password
       --password password
              Use  password  to encrypt zipfile entries (if any).  THIS IS INSECURE!  Many multi-user operating systems provide ways for any user to see the current command line of any other user; even on
              stand-alone systems there is always the threat of over-the-shoulder peeking.  Storing the plaintext password as part of a command line in an automated script is even worse.  Whenever  possi‐
              ble,  use  the  non-echoing,  interactive prompt to enter passwords.  (And where security is truly important, use strong encryption such as Pretty Good Privacy instead of the relatively weak
```

So as you note, `-p` and `-P` are different options that do different things. The option you need then is `-P`.

Comment: way nicer than my answer!

Comment: @Marcus Müller I was about to accept your answer. Thank you!